# Maximum of two columns in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

this should be quite simple but I still didn't find a way. I have to compute a new column with a value of maximum of columns col1 and col2. So if col1 is 2 and col2 is 4, the new_col should have 4. And so on. It's in a Pyspark dataframe.
I tried `df=df.withColumn("new_col",max("col1","col2"))`, but got the error "_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". So what would be the correct way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try with **[`greatest`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.greatest.html)**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
output = df.withColumn("new_col",F.greatest(*["col1","col2"]))
```